# Calculate percent from total observations in r gtsummary::tbl_summary?

Tags: r, gtsummary

Issue: In `gtsummary` the `tbl_summary` function calculates column percent out of the total non-missing observations. I would like `gtsummary` to calculate percent from the total of missing and non-missing observations.

Example from the `gtsummary` Table Gallery at http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/gallery.html

```
trial[c("trt", "age", "grade")] %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = trt, 
    missing = "no",
    statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{median} ({p25}, {p75}) [N = {N_nonmiss}]"
  ) %>%
  modify_header(stat_by = md("**{level}**<br>N =  {n} ({style_percent(p)}%)")) %>%
  add_n() %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  modify_spanning_header(starts_with("stat_") ~ "**Chemotherapy Treatment**")
```

Grade has no missing observations so 35 people with Grade 1 disease in the Drug A group is 35/98 (36%).

Now, recoding Grade 3 to missing:

```
trial$grade[trial$grade %in% "III"] <- NA
trial$grade <- droplevels(trial$grade)
```

Re-run `tbl_summary`:

```
trial[c("trt", "age", "grade")] %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = trt, 
    missing = "no",
    statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{median} ({p25}, {p75}) [N = {N_nonmiss}]"
  ) %>%
  modify_header(stat_by = md("**{level}**<br>N =  {n} ({style_percent(p)}%)")) %>%
  add_n() %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  modify_spanning_header(starts_with("stat_") ~ "**Chemotherapy Treatment**")
```

Grade 1 is now expressed as n = 35 out of 67 (52%) non-missing obs. in the Drug A group. I would still like the percent to be expressed as 36% of 98 people. Is there a way to do this in `gtsummary`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to get what you're looking for is to make the missing values explicit NA using the `forcats::fct_explicit_na()` function.  When the NA value is a level of a factor, it'll be included in the denominator for percentage calculations.

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)


trial %>%
  select(response, trt) %>%
  # make missing value explicit for categorical variables, using fct_explicit_na
  mutate(response = factor(response) %>% fct_explicit_na()) %>%
  # summarize data
  tbl_summary(by = trt)
```

[image]

Does this solution work for you?

Comment: D.Sjoberg Hi there! I have tried this but it isn't working. I posted my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64884901/calculating-percent-for-missing-values-using-gtsummary-in-rstudio?