# Calculating percent for missing values using gtsummary in Rstudio

Tags: r, gtsummary

My question is a bit similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63640473/calculate-percent-from-total-observations-in-r-gtsummarytbl-summary) here.

I have this following codes:

```
library(gtsummary)
basicvars <- names(isoq) %in% c("homeless_nonself", "test_result")
basictable <- isoq[basicvars]
    # summarize the data
table1 <- tbl_summary(basictable, missing = "always",                              
                      missing_text = "(Missing)",
                      percent = "cell",
                      type = all_dichotomous() ~"categorical"
) %>%
  bold_labels()

############Selecting the order of variables 
basiccompletetable <- basictable %>% select(test_result,homeless_nonself)
mutate(test_result = factor(test_result) %>% fct_explicit_na()) %>%
  
table3 <- tbl_summary(basiccompletetable, #missing = "always", missing_text = "(Missing)",
                      percent = "cell",
                      label = list( 
                        test_result ~ "COVID-19 Test Result",
                        homeless_nonself ~ "Homeless",
                        
                      ),
                      sort = list(
                        test_result ~ "frequency",
                        homeless_nonself ~ "frequency",
                        ),
                      type = list(all_character() ~ "categorical")
) %>%
  modify_spanning_header(starts_with("stat_") ~ "**All**") %>%
  modify_header(label = "**Variable**") %>%  # update the column header
  #add_n() %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  as_gt() %>%
  gt::tab_source_note(gt::md("*This data is simulated*"))
table3
```

It spits the output (not the complete output)

[image]

I am trying to show the percentages for the missing values. Tried first with test_result. Used this line of code `mutate(test_result = factor(test_result) %>% fct_explicit_na()) %>%` to what was suggested in the earlier question. However, I am seeing the same table as my output and there are no percentages on the missing values for the variable test_result.

Any suggestions why this is not working? Thanks

Comment: Can you make this question reproducible? Add `dput(isoq)` to your question.

Comment: What is the dput tag for? I can look into this further if you update to make the question reproducible so I can run it on my machine as well.

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg Thanks a lot for responding to the question! I have never used dput for so can remove it. I was responding to the previous comment.

Comment: I think @Ronak was referring to a method that would make your data available to us so we can answer your question. Can you update the code using an example dataset? Perhaps using the trial dataset in the gtsummary package?

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg Sounds good! I will try with the trial dataset and will make an edit

Comment: Great! When creating your example, please keep in mind that minimal examples are best; including the fewest lines of code necessary to replicate your issue.https://www.tidyverse.org/help/

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg Btw I made an update of the image output. I want to see the percentages of the missing observations for each variable. Even though they are 0% by using percent = "cell".  I will update with the trial data as well later.